# React-Native: Flatlist with if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([
{id: '1', name: 'firstName', place: 'BER'},
{id: '2', name: 'SecondName', place: 'BER'},
{id: '3', name: 'thirdName', place: 'VIE'},
{id: '4', name: 'fourthName', place: 'VIE'},
]);
```

```
<Flatlist
data={info}
renderItems={({ items }) => (
  if (items.id < 3) {
   <Text style={{color:'red'}}>{items.name}</Text>
  }
  if else (items.id => 3) {
   <Text style={{color:'blue'}}>{items.name}</Text>
  }
)}
/>
```

Im unable to use the if else statements like this, I have also tried it using index, but the code does compile in both the cases.

What I want is that depending on the 'id' different code should compile.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct desestruture is `{{ item }}`.

Also, in your case, you can't use short syntax return, since your return isn't defined by one-line code

```
({{item}}) => <YourComponent/>
```

To

```
 ({{item}}) => { 
        return <YourComponent/> 
    }
```

In your case

```
<Flatlist
data={info}
renderItems={({ item }) => {
  if (item.id < 3) {
   return <Text style={{color:'red'}}>{item.name}</Text>
  }
  if else (items.id => 3) {
   return <Text style={{color:'blue'}}>{item.name}</Text>
  }
}}
/>
```

If you want to use short syntax, you also could do :

```
   <Flatlist
    data={info}
    renderItems={({ item }) =>  item.id < 3 ?
       (<Text style={{color:'red'}}>{item.name}</Text>) :
       (<Text style={{color:'blue'}}>{item.name}</Text>)
    }
```

If you want to scale this for more than just 1 condition, **isn’t a good practice nesting more than one ternary operator**, but you can achieve this with

```
condition1? <YourComponent1/> : condition2? <YourComponent2/> : <YourComponent3/>
```

In my opinion, you should not use short syntax since it let the code less legible in this specific case.

Comment: Im using the flatlist inside the return, is there any other way around it, the short sytax works. But I want to know if there a way with using full if statements as in the future I might have multiple cases

Comment: It isn’t a good practice nesting more than one ternary operator, but you can achieve this with condition? <YourComponent1/> : condition2? <YourComponent2/> : <YourComponent3/>. In my opinion, you should not use short syntax since it let the code less legible in this specific case

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator `?` `:`

```js
<Flatlist
  data={info}
  renderItems={({ items }) => (
    <Text style={{ color: items.id < 3 ? 'red' : 'blue' }}>{items.name}</Text>
  )}
/>;
```